# Checking variable changes in Jquery or Javascript without setInterval

Tags: javascript, variables, listener

I need to check my variable **mutexSelect** as follows:

```
window.setInterval( function(){
   if (mutexSelect === true) {
      mutexSelect = false;
      makeIntoSelect(newSelectedItem);
   }
},300);
```

But it's not like how would like to have. Sometimes it leads to further conflicts and not calling **makeIntoSelect** function. Are there any other options to watch a variable by JS or jQuery? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: look into mutation observers

Comment: @SterlingArcher  Is it ok to use mutation observer for this? I thought mutation observers are best fit to observe dom changes.

Comment: @karthick good question, I'm not 100% familiar with observers but that's really the next best option I think